# wxPython: Exit Fullscreen

Tags: python, wxpython

To display a wxPython window in full screen mode you use:

```
ShowFullScreen(True)
```

How do you get out of full screen though? I've tried the obvious way:

```
ShowFullScreen(True)
sleep(5)
ShowFullScreen(False)
```

This doesn't work though. When I run the script, nothing appears. After 5 seconds a window roughly 200x250 appears in the top-left corner of the screen, without anything inside of it. It doesn't appear to have any borders either.

If I change this to

```
showFullScreen(True)
```

then I get stuck with a full screen window that I have to use Alt + F2 -> xkill to get out of.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you need to `Show()` the window first. (According to the [documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxtoplevelwindow.html#wxtoplevelwindowshowfullscreen), you shouldn't have to. Maybe this is a bug.) I tested on Mac OS X and Windows - they both exhibit issues if you don't call `Show()` first.

Also note that you shouldn't sleep in the main GUI thread. You'll hang the UI. Using `CallLater` is one potential solution, as shown in my example.

Working example:

```
import wx

def main():
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'Full Screen Test')
    frame.Show()
    frame.ShowFullScreen(True)
    wx.CallLater(5000, frame.ShowFullScreen, False)
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for ShowFullScreen reads:
ShowFullScreen(show, style=wx.FULLSCREEN_ALL)

```
Depending on the value of show parameter the window is either shown full screen or restored to its normal state.

Parameters:

    show (bool)
    style (long): is a bit list containing some or all of the following values, which indicate what elements of the window to hide in full-screen mode:
        wx.FULLSCREEN_NOMENUBAR
        wx.FULLSCREEN_NOTOOLBAR
        wx.FULLSCREEN_NOSTATUSBAR
        wx.FULLSCREEN_NOBORDER
        wx.FULLSCREEN_NOCAPTION
        wx.FULLSCREEN_ALL (all of the above)
```

So put your Full Screen toggle event/s in a Menu and start full screen mode with:
`self.window.ShowFullScreen(True, style=(wx.FULLSCREEN_NOTOOLBAR | wx.FULLSCREEN_NOSTATUSBAR |wx.FULLSCREEN_NOBORDER |wx.FULLSCREEN_NOCAPTION))`

Note that I omitted wx.FULLSCREEN_NOMENUBAR, in this way you will still be able to access the menu to turn full screen mode off again.